# Getting the source .rst file path in Sphinx extension

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am writing a Sphinx extension and I need to know the current page's `.rst` source file location to extract some version control system information of it. How can I get this information in my event handler / which event handler I should use?

Example:

```
def on_html_page_context(app, pagename, templatename, context, doctree):
    if doctree:
        print doctree.source

def setup(app):
    app.require_sphinx('1.0')
    app.connect('html-page-context', on_html_page_context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with a small change to the event handler in your example:

```
def on_html_page_context(app, pagename, templatename, context, doctree):
    if doctree:
        print doctree.attributes['source'] # Path to .rst file

def setup(app):
    app.connect('html-page-context', on_html_page_context)
```